# Find the superficial measure of a compact

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been struggling with this problem for a bit :

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^3}$, we define the superficial measure of $S$ as follows :

$$\mathcal{A}(S):= \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\nu_3\{x\in\mathbb{R^3}: \epsilon \ge \operatorname{dist}(x,S)\}.$$

We want to compute this for $S$ compact.

To give myself an idea, I first took $S$ an Euclidean sphere of center $y\in\mathbb{R^3}$ and radius $r$ (that's what was advised in the problem):

$S=\{x\in\mathbb{R^3}: \operatorname{dist}(x,y)=r\}$.

This gives us $\{x\in\mathbb{R^3}: \epsilon \ge \operatorname{dist}(x,S)\}=B_c(y,r+\epsilon)\setminus B_o(y,r-\epsilon)$.

Thus,

\begin{align}
\nu_3\{B_c(y,r+\epsilon)\setminus B_o(y,r-\epsilon)\}&=4\pi((r+\epsilon)^2-(r-\epsilon)^2)\\& = \frac{4}{3}\pi((r+\epsilon-r+\epsilon)(r+\epsilon+r-\epsilon))\\&=\frac{4}{3}\pi\times2\epsilon\times2r
\end{align}

And finally, $\mathcal{A}(S)= \frac{8}{3}\pi r$.

I haven't been able to solve the problem for compacts though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldnt it be $\nu_3 (B_c (y,r+\varepsilon) - B_0(y, r- \varepsilon)) = \frac{4\pi}{3} ((r+\varepsilon)^3 - (r-\varepsilon)^3)$ ?

Comment: Yes indeed, what I wrote was the area. I'll edit it, thank you